# WP Bakery Page Builder (formerly Visual Composer) mandatory fields in custom elements

Tags: visual-composer

Is there any way to add a mandatory / required field in a custom VC element?

I cannot find any option like this here:

https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_map/

I think it should be something like:

"required" => true in the param section...

But is there a way to do it? a hook/filter maybe?

Thanks